# How to use simultaneously AJAX and eventsource?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server-sent-events

I'm creating a chat using PHP, JavaScript and SQL and I have some troubles with my JavaScript. In my chat I use the eventsource object to update my chat and AJAX to send new messages. But when I use a while loop in my PHP document that the eventsouce uses, my javascript does not send requests via AJAX until the connection to the user is broken (The message is not saved in my database when I click on the button that triggers the function that sends the message via AJAX, but when I close my window the database contains the new messages).
To help you here are my codes.

**main.js**

```
var httpRequest;

function sendMessage(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    if(!httpRequest){
        console.log("Failure : HTTP Request not available");
        return false;
    }else{
        var documentURL = "http://chat/webs/contact/up.php";
        var sender="Name";
        var message = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        var postData = "sender="+encodeURIComponent(sender)+"&message="+encodeURIComponent(message);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = checkRequestStatus;
        httpRequest.open('POST', documentURL);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        httpRequest.send(postData);
        return true;
    }
}

function checkRequestStatus(){
    if(httpRequest.readyState === 4){
        document.getElementById('textBox').value = "";
    }
}

const evtSource = new EventSource("http://chat/webs/contact/down.php");
evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
};
```

**down.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
$db = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "dbname");
if($db->connect_errno){
    die("Error:".$db->connect_errno.$db->connect_error);
}
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `messages`");
$messageNumber = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while(true){
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `messages`");
    if($messageNumber < mysqli_num_rows($query)){
        $reps = 1;
        while($answer = $query -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            if($reps > $messageNumber){
                $messageNotification = array('sender'=>$answer['Sender'], 'content'=>$answer['Content']);
                $JSONMessage = json_encode($messageNotification);
                echo "data:{$JSONMessage}\n\n";
            }
            $reps += 1;
        }
    }
    
    $messageNumber = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    if ( connection_aborted() ) break;
    sleep(0.1);
}
?>
```

**up.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $db = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
    if($db->connect_errno){
        die("Error : ".$db->connect_error." ".$db->connect_errno);
    }else{
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sender = $_POST['sender'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $conversation = 1;
        $date = date("d/m/y");
        $query->bind_param("ssis", $sender, $message, $conversation, $date);
        $query->execute();
    }
?>
```

Thank you for trying to help me.

**EDIT**:After some testing my problem is that my http request does not leave the readystate 1 (that means recieved), I suppose that my server does not treat the request until the user has close his connection to the server.

Comment: It would make more sense to use websockets then you've got two-way communication on a single channel

Comment: Yes it's possible the server only allows one active connection per user at a time. You didn't say if this is your own local server, or shared hosting, or VPS or something else?